# Nao consigo atribuir um valor do banco de dados para uma variável php

Tags: php, mysql

Olá pessoal sou iniciante em php e estou com uma dificuldade tenho uma tabela de usuarios (id, login, senha, nivel) de acordo com o nivel do usuario deverá ir para um painel diferente, a parte de login esta ok, somente o valor do nível não consigo atribuir a uma variável para fazer uma comparação e direcionar o usuário para seu devido painel

segue o codigo:

```
<?php

$usuario = $_POST['user'];
$senha = $_POST['password'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_usuarios WHERE login = '$usuario' and senha = '$senha'") or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_num_rows($sql) or die (mysql_error());
if($row == 1){
    $nivel = 0;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_usuarios WHERE nivel = '$nivel'");

    echo $nivel; 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['user'];
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $_POST['password'];
    echo "<center>Login efetuado com Sucesso!!!</center> ";
    //echo "<script>loginsuccessfully()</script>";
    switch($nivel){
        case 1:
            echo "<script>diretor()</script>";
        break;
    }

}else{

    echo "<center>Login ou senha invalidos aguarde um instante para tentar novamente!</center>";
    echo "<script>loginfailed()</script>";
}
```

Comment: seu  $nivel = 0; é sempre igual a 0

Comment: Bom dia amadeu obrigado por se propor a ajudar eu atribui zero pea mim ver se no código mais abaixo ela mudaria de valor, se eu mudar manualmente o valor de $nivel = 1; ele executa o script certinho e redireciona... Mas esse valor eu ja tenho no banco e nao consigo recuperar ele e atribuir a $nivel entendeu achei umas coisas na web mas nao funcionaram, talvez eu tenha implementado errado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não mostrou como esta tentando atribuir ou se esta acontecendo algum erro, basicamente deveria ser feito isso:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_usuarios WHERE login = '$usuario' and senha = '$senha'") or die (mysql_error());
$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

$nivel = $array['nivel'];
```

Comment: Olá a Reji Obrigado pela resposta assim que eu chegar em casa tentarei implementar

Comment: Reji, muito Obrigado essa implementação deu certo (y)

Comment: Show de bola. ;)

Comment: Deveria marcar a resposta como aceite colocando um certo verde nela :)

Comment: Olá Amadeu Antunes, marquei Gostaria de me desculpar pois sou novato no uso do stack.